# More URL options HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, servlets, httprequest

I pass parameters to the server line

```
"login=testAva4&nick=testAvaNick&social=vk&saurl=http://domain.example?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3&maurl=1"
```

waiting as the value saurl="http://domain.example?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3"

but i get http://domain.example?param1=1 and param2=2 param3=3

From Eclipse debug

```
req->_parameters

{maurl=1, nick=testAvaNick, param2=2, saurl=http://domain.example?param1=1, param3=3, social=vk, login=testAva4}
```

Gets the parameters in the code like this:

```
public class AddProfileServlet extends PlacerServlet {

    //Add new profile method
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //Receive variables from URL
        String login = req.getParameter("login");
        String nick = req.getParameter("nick");
        String social = req.getParameter("social");
        String saurl = req.getParameter("saurl");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use URLEncoding on the saurl parameter. 
Look at URLCodec at the commons codec [enter link description here](http://commons.apache.org/codec/userguide.html) project. 
I don't think you will need to encode the entire parameters part, but just the value for this specific parameter. 
You can encode a string using:

```
URLCodec codec = new URLCodec();
String encodedValue = codec.encode(valueToEncode);
```

And you should use encodedValue as the value passed to the saurl parameter.

Comment: request sent to server from iPhone. how to code it URL on the iPhone

Comment: I am sure you can find some iPhone library that does that. Are you sending it from the safari browser, or from a custom made application?

Comment: Then try finding code that performs URL encoding for iOS. You can look at the code of URLCodec java (it's open source) and port it to objective-C, I guess.